# Upload files evenly on servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, file-upload, distributed

Users will be uploading files to my website and I need to distribute them evenly on more than one server and also I need to have column in DB that says to which server the particular file was upload.

So here is my design.

1. Have enum of server names i.e server1, server2, server3.
2. Get the last Uploaded server name from DB
3. If the last uploaded server was server1, then current file should be uploaded to server2 and update DB, 
   if last uploaded server was server3 \, then current file should be uploaded to server1 and update DB

Application and DB is currently hosted on single server but in future we will move to load balancing.

Let me know if there is any best method other than this.

Comment: I think that it would be best to figure out how you are going to perform your load balancing. The method that you are proposing will only leave you with one choice: static DNS values that route to a server. Which is not ideal if you want true fail-over load balancing scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should work depending on how your customers use it. I'll give you a quick breakdown of how I've seen this done before.

- Round robin DNS (assign multiple IP addresses to the same domain)
- Multiple web servers who get traffic based on the DNS round robin
- Each web server then has it's own dedicated SQL server.
- SQL servers use replication to keep data syncronized.
- Single storage server for file uploads. (Unless file uploads is the main function I doubt you'd need >1)

Pros: 
VERY easily scale-able until you hit massive levels of traffic, at which point you'll need to rethink the SQL piece.

When purchasing hardware you can spend your money in certain areas to focus it on being a file server/SQL or web server

Cons:
This doesn't provide any true redundancy. And arguably makes it worse due to the tiered approach. This could be resolved with some managed DNS but that still isn't a perfect approach and I know some sys admins who cringe at the thought of managed DNS.